# Apache Shiro decide what role to use after login

Tags: spring, authentication, roles, shiro

I have an existing legacy project which is built with  Spring 3 and Apache Shiro for authentication and authorization. It uses a JDBC realm.

We have the authorization implemented with permissions assigned to authorities and authorities to users.

The scenario is like:

- use1: fooRole, barRole
- fooRole: foo.permission.1, foo.permission.2
- barRole: bar.permission.1, bar.permission.2

I've been requested to login with "user1" and afer login select whhich role "user1" wants to operate with. For example:

1. Correct login user1
2. select fooRole or barRole
3. select fooRole and now operate with "foo.permission.1, foo.permission.2" permissions.

[According tho the shiro architecture](https://shiro.apache.org/architecture.html) in my application I have a "Subject" accesible as read only. And the security mannager gets the information from my database. I can check if the subject has a specific role or permission. But once I've loged in I dont see a way to alter user roles to the subject.

I think this is not the way Apache Shiro is suposed to work, and this may not be the best of practices, but anyway:
Does any of you have an idea to explicit select one of asigned roles to operate only with, in Apache Shiro?

Thanks you all for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change user permissions at runtime. There is a discussion about this issue [here](http://shiro-user.582556.n2.nabble.com/Changing-permissions-at-runtime-td3282662.html). This is something you have to do in a custom Shiro realm since it's the only place you have access to the `AuthorizationInfo` by design. The `AuthorizationInfo` stores authorisation data like permissions and roles represented by a single subject. There is no getter and setter outside of your realm for a subject to assign roles and permissions. You can always check:

- if a subject holds a permission: `SecurityUtils.getSubject().isPermitted();`
- if a subject holds a role: `SecurityUtils.getSubject().hasRoles();`

The simplest implementation of [`AuthorizationInfo`](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.4.0/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/authz/AuthorizationInfo.html) is [`SimpleAuthorizationInfo`](https://shiro.apache.org/static/1.4.0/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/authz/SimpleAuthorizationInfo.html).

**IMHO** this is a bad practise for many reasons. This is not what Shiro is build for.

Comment: Thanks it helps me a lot. And I agree.

Comment: Why is it bad practice for many reasons? Only reason I can see is that Shiro wasn't developed with standard RBAC in mind -- activation and deactivation of roles within a session has been a fundamental concept of RBAC since the mid 90s and is in the ANSI/NIST standard. It should be *good* practice for many reasons!